# My JOIN SQL query tooks to long to complete

Tags: mysql, sql

My query takes to long when i am putting the limit up with limit 1 it is still acceptable but with 10 it takes 25 seconds.

```sql
SELECT *,INET_ATON(L.`ip`) as test
FROM `access_logs` L
JOIN `ip2location_db11` I ON INET_ATON(L.`ip`) between ip_from AND ip_to
LIMIT 1
```

Query took 0.6031 seconds

```sql
SELECT *,INET_ATON(L.`ip`) as test
FROM `access_logs` L
JOIN `ip2location_db11` I ON INET_ATON(L.`ip`) between ip_from AND ip_to
LIMIT 2
```

Query took 0.7878 seconds

```sql
SELECT *,INET_ATON(L.`ip`) as test
FROM `access_logs` L
JOIN `ip2location_db11` I ON INET_ATON(L.`ip`) between ip_from AND ip_to
LIMIT 10
```

Query took 25.6616 seconds.

a better way of doing it (thanks to @PeterHe)

```sql
SELECT L.*, I.* 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM access_logs 
  ORDER by id desc LIMIT 10
) L 
INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 I 
ON INET_ATON(L.ip) 
BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
```

Query took 5.0731 seconds.

table structure

Database ip2location_db11

```
1   ip_fromIndex    int(10)         UNSIGNED    Yes     NULL            
2   ip_toIndex      int(10)         UNSIGNED    Yes     NULL            
3   country_code    char(2)         utf8_bin    Yes     NULL            
4   country_name    varchar(64)     utf8_bin    Yes     
5   region_name     varchar(128)    utf8_bin    Yes     
6   city_name       varchar(128)    utf8_bin    Yes     NULL            
7   latitude        double                      Yes     NULL                
8   longitude       double                      Yes     NULL                
9   zip_code        varchar(30)     utf8_bin    Yes     NULL 
10  time_zone       varchar(8)      utf8_bin    Yes     NULL
```

Database access_logs

```
1   id          int(11)                                 No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT  
2   tid         varchar(36)     utf8_general_ci         No  None            
3   ip          varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci         No  None            
4   useragent   text            utf8_general_ci         No  None                         
5   time        varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci         No  None            
6   cookies     text            utf8_general_ci         No  None            
7   page_s      text            utf8_general_ci         No  None             
8   page_a      text            utf8_general_ci         No  None             
9   referer     text            utf8_general_ci         No  None            
10  method      varchar(10)     utf8_general_ci         No  None            
11  lang        varchar(3)      utf8_general_ci         No  None            
12  flang       text            utf8_general_ci         No  None             
13  info        text            utf8_general_ci         Yes NULL
```

I hope to get this a lot faster because I'm planning to do a query with limit 25

Comment: create necessary `index` on your `table`.

Comment: Can you post the table structure? Use function on column in JOIN or WHERE condition will prevent the server to use any index.

Comment: @PeterHe i have updated my question

Comment: Might also be a problem with the range check. Try to make a subselect with the `BETWEEN` clause and join the result. This might eliminate entries which don't need be joined thus saving time.

Comment: What's your criteria for LIMIT 10. You query just randomly takes 10 records without the ORDER BY clause.  You will need to add the column for ip_int in the access_logs table and create an index on it for better performance.

Comment: The thumb rule for index is to create an index on the columns being used in join clause, where clause and order by clause.

Comment: @PeterHe I have now added ORDER BY to my query `SELECT *,INET_ATON(L.ip) as test FROM access_logs L JOIN ip2location_db11 I ON INET_ATON(L.ip) between ip_from AND ip_to ORDER BY L.id DESC LIMIT 2` and what do you mean with "add the column for ip_int in the access_logs table and create an index on it for better performance"

Comment: Did you try moving the between filter to a where clause?

Comment: ALTER TABLE access_logs ADD ip_int int not null DEFAULT 0;

Comment: UPDATE access_los SET ip_int=INET_ATON(`ip`);

Comment: Also add an index on ip_int. Now in your query, you use ip_int, not INET_ATON(L.`ip`)

Comment: IF change table structure is not possible, you can use a subquery to get the rows you want first: SELECT L.* FROM  (SELECT * FROM access_logs  ORDER by id desc LIMIT 2) L INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 I ON INET_ATON(L.ip) between ip_from AND ip_to

Comment: @PeterHe I have the following query now `SELECT L.*, I.* FROM (SELECT * FROM access_logs ORDER by id desc LIMIT 10) L INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 I ON INET_ATON(L.ip) between ip_from AND ip_to` it is much faster now `Query took 5.0731 seconds.` is there any way i can make it even faster?

Comment: Do you have index on ip_from and ip_to in the table ip2location_db11? If not, add an index. Otherwise you will need to change the table structure as suggested above.

Comment: @PeterHe It still tooks about 5 seconds when i have added the indexes and added the row ip_int to my database. Maybe i need to filter first some data from ip2location database because it is a large database. So how do i do that?

Comment: Yes, filter in the subquery with the LIMIT and then join with the ip2location_db11  using the new ip_int column

Comment: @PeterHe i think i already have done that `SELECT L.*, I.* FROM (SELECT * FROM access_logs ORDER by id desc LIMIT 10) L INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 I ON INET_ATON(L.ip) between ip_from AND ip_to` but it is still slow (5 seconds) if you have a faster solution can you send me a example query?

Comment: You are not using the new column ip_int in the join. It should be: SELECT L.*, I.* FROM (SELECT * FROM access_logs ORDER by id desc LIMIT 10) L INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 I ON L.ip_int between ip_from AND ip_to

Comment: @PeterHe sorry, i already tried that that is a lot faster but still 5 seconds depending on the ip  `SELECT L.*, I.* FROM (SELECT * FROM access_logs ORDER by id desc LIMIT 10) L INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 I ON ip_int between ip_from AND ip_to`

Answer (score 0):

As per the order of execution, the Join is executed before the limit. hence just be placing the limit does not improve the performance. Ensure the right indexes are in place and try again.